Convert Pandas dataframe of objects to a dataframe of vectors
I have a Pandas dataframe (over 1k of rows). There are numbers, objects, strings, and Boolean values in my dataframe. I want to convert each 'cell' of the dataframe to a vector, and work with the resulting vectors. I then plan to compare each row of vectors for similarities.
For example, My data is:
Col 0,Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,Col 4,Col 5,Col 6,Col 7,Col 8,Col 9,Col 10

12,65e1e35b7fe333,harry Joe,1,FALSE,swe,1,142.158.0.2,10.10.0.2,text1,0
13,65e1e35b7fe599,allen,1,FALSE,swe,1,142.158.0.20,10.10.0.20,text2,0
14,65e1e35b7fe165,carter,1,FALSE,swe,1,142.158.0.21,10.10.0.21,text3,0

I want to end up with a dataframe of vectors that looks like:
Col 0,Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,Col 4,Col 5,Col 6,Col 7,Col 8,Col 9,Col 10

Vect1,Vect2,Vect3,Vect4,Vect5,Vect6,Vect7,Vect8,Vect9,Vect10,Vect11

Vect12,Vect 13,Vect 14,Vect4,Vect5,Vect6,Vect7,Vect 15,Vect 16,Vect 17,Vect11

Vect18,Vect 19,Vect 20,Vect4,Vect5,Vect6,Vect7,Vect 21,Vect 22,Vect 23,Vect11

Is there a good way to do this in Python w SciKit maybe?
I have tried:
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer

df=mydata

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

# Transform the data to feature vectors
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df)
X = pd.DataFrame(_X.todense(), index=df.index, columns=vectorizer.vocabulary_)
X.head()

# Labels
y = df['label']

What I got was:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 14
     11 vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
     13 # Transform the text data to feature vectors
---> 14 X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df)
     16 X = pd.DataFrame(_X.todense(), index=df.index, columns=vectorizer.vocabulary_)
     17 X.head()

File /anaconda/envs/xxx_py38/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py:2079, in TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   2072 self._check_params()
   2073 self._tfidf = TfidfTransformer(
   2074     norm=self.norm,
   2075     use_idf=self.use_idf,
   2076     smooth_idf=self.smooth_idf,
   2077     sublinear_tf=self.sublinear_tf,
   2078 )
-> 2079 X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
   2080 self._tfidf.fit(X)
   2081 # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so
   2082 # we set copy to False

File /anaconda/envs/xxx_py38/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py:1338, in CountVectorizer.fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1330             warnings.warn(
   1331                 "Upper case characters found in"
   1332                 " vocabulary while 'lowercase'"
   1333                 " is True. These entries will not"
   1334                 " be matched with any documents"
   1335             )
   1336             break
-> 1338 vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1340 if self.binary:
   1341     X.data.fill(1)

File /anaconda/envs/xxx_py38/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py:1207, in CountVectorizer._count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
   1205 values = _make_int_array()
   1206 indptr.append(0)
-> 1207 for doc in raw_documents:
   1208     feature_counter = {}
   1209     for feature in analyze(doc):

TypeError: 'Data' object is not iterable


Why do they have to be vectors?   Having a row of 1-element vectors seems pointless.

What do you mean by 'vector'? Give a more specific example, using actual values, so we can understand what you are trying to do. Note that tf-idf works on collections of documents, not rows of tabular data. Or maybe text1 is a document? Sharing something that looks like your actual data will help figure it out.

@MattHall the table above is some of my actual data

I want to vectorize my data in order to compare the similarity of the rows as stated in the question

I was thinking that a vector for each element would make it easier to assess similarity as opposed to a single vector for the entire row.

@TimRoberts, vectors, or some numerical representation of the data would make it easier to assess similarity.

It sounds like you want to treat each feature as a categorical variable and encode it, eg as a one-hot vector? I don't think the tf-idf vectorizer will help... maybe look at label encoders, or better yet entity embeddings or something like that.

A vector containing a string is no more useful than a string.  I think you want to convert all of the elements to NUMBERS, not vectors.    Label encoders is a great suggestion.

@TimRoberts you are correct. Thanks for that suggestion

In looking at label encoders - that is intended for targets (y) not X .  My data is X (features). entity embeddings is for categorical data. so that would only work on some columns. Vectors should be a numerical representation - a scalar and direction. so I still think it should be vectorized.

You want a single vector for each row. Label encoders are usually used on targets, but it's common to encode features -- so give it a try. You can't turn a scalar into a vector with adding some information, so you can probably just use the numerical values as-is. Or, maybe you have some custom encoding in mind -- just give it a go. BTW you need to expand your definition of vector to include the concept of a point in n-D space, not just magnitude/direction.

@MattHall ty!  I am thinking of converting everything (each character in a cell) to acsii.  that would give it a numerical representation that I could use for comparison,  what do you think?

@Tavi Each character will give your an ascii value. So for each row there will be variable number of numbers. How do you intend to make a fixed size vector out of them?

Go through the code. I think , This is what you want.
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col 0': [10, 100, 1000],
    'Col 1': ['65e1e35b7fe333', '65e1e35b7fe599', '65e1e35b7fe165'],
    'Col 2': [True, False, False],
    'Col 3': ['Protijayi', 'Roopa', 'Gina'],

})
print(df)
'''
  Col 0           Col 1  Col 2      Col 3
0     10  65e1e35b7fe333   True  Protijayi
1    100  65e1e35b7fe599  False      Roopa
2   1000  65e1e35b7fe165  False       Gina
'''
# Define transformations for different types of data
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', StandardScaler(), ['Col 0']),  # For numerical columns
        ('cat', OneHotEncoder(), ['Col 1']),  # For categorical columns
        ('bool', 'passthrough', ['Col 2']),  # For Boolean columns (already 0 or 1)
        ('text', TfidfVectorizer(), 'Col 3')  # For text data
    ],
    remainder='drop'  # Drop untransformed columns
)

# Apply transformations
X = preprocessor.fit_transform(df)

# Convert the resulting matrix to a DataFrame for easy inspection
X_df = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray() if hasattr(X, 'toarray') else X)

print(X_df)
'''
         0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
0 -0.805387  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1 -0.604040  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
2  1.409428  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
'''

Method 2 :
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

#DataFrame with 20 rows.df.shape = (20, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col_0': [10, 100, 1000, 500, 200, 50, 600, 300, 800, 400, 150, 700, 900, 100,
               350, 250, 50, 450, 750, 850],
    'Col_1': [
        '65e1e35b7fe333', '65e1e35b7fe599', '65e1e35b7fe165', '65e1e35b7fe444',
        '65e1e35b7fe555', '65e1e35b7fe666', '65e1e35b7fe777', '65e1e35b7fe888',
        '65e1e35b7fe999', '65e1e35b7fea11', '65e1e35b7fea22', '65e1e35b7fea33',
        '65e1e35b7fea44', '65e1e35b7fea55', '65e1e35b7fea66', '65e1e35b7fea77',
        '65e1e35b7fea88', '65e1e35b7fea99', '65e1e35b7fea10', '65e1e35b7fea20'
    ],
    'Col_2': [
        True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True,
        False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True,
        True, False, True, False
    ],
    'Col_3': [
        'Protijayi', 'Roopa', 'Gina', 'Anna', 'John', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Zara',
        'Tom', 'Jerry', 'Donald', 'Mickey', 'HeMan', 'Soudipta', 'Phantom', 'YogiBear',
        'Thundarr', 'GummyBears', 'Tabu', 'Stanley'
    ],
})
print(df.shape)#(20, 4)
print(df)
# Label Encoding for categorical data
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
df['Col_1'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['Col_1'])

# Pipeline for text transformation and dimensionality reduction
text_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(max_features=50)),  # Adjust max_features if needed
    ('pca', PCA(n_components=16))  # Reduce to 16 components
])

# Preprocessor with ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', StandardScaler(), ['Col_0']),
        ('cat', 'passthrough', ['Col_1']),  # Already label encoded
        ('bool', 'passthrough', ['Col_2']),
        ('text', text_pipeline, 'Col_3')
    ]
)

# Apply transformations
X = preprocessor.fit_transform(df)

# Create the appropriate number of column names
columns = ['Col_0_scaled', 'Col_1_encoded', 'Col_2'] + [f'Col_3_pca_{i+1}' for i in range(16)]

# Convert the resulting matrix to a DataFrame
X_df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=columns)

print(X_df.to_string())
'''
   Col_0_scaled  Col_1_encoded  Col_2  Col_3_pca_1  Col_3_pca_2  Col_3_pca_3  Col_3_pca_4  Col_3_pca_5  Col_3_pca_6  Col_3_pca_7  Col_3_pca_8  Col_3_pca_9  Col_3_pca_10  Col_3_pca_11  Col_3_pca_12  Col_3_pca_13  Col_3_pca_14  Col_3_pca_15  Col_3_pca_16
0      -1.334401            1.0    1.0    -0.073105    -0.146901     0.067336     0.125044     0.090760     0.009809     0.305958     0.139551     0.156774      0.527018      0.060816     -0.203797     -0.374745     -0.141668     -0.421094      0.188830
1      -1.045361            4.0    0.0     0.115282    -0.015415    -0.150784    -0.360184    -0.080453     0.019688    -0.031309     0.255278     0.108915     -0.311483     -0.167477      0.008409     -0.300929     -0.220409      0.084341     -0.017631
2       1.845039            0.0    0.0     0.160889    -0.020035     0.330186     0.127126     0.273287    -0.071395    -0.319679     0.219527    -0.279286     -0.004423     -0.239776     -0.416249      0.067402      0.081037     -0.241028     -0.213331
3       0.239261            2.0    1.0     0.554679     0.130482     0.081359     0.118546     0.214038    -0.363213     0.385183    -0.148279    -0.027544     -0.001442     -0.244361      0.424055      0.026407     -0.058623      0.014459      0.048063
4      -0.724206            3.0    0.0     0.307266     0.050949     0.310680    -0.297831    -0.383361     0.129143    -0.158281    -0.122024     0.075167      0.182113      0.224166      0.004674      0.072569      0.380125     -0.010579      0.439877
5      -1.205939            5.0    1.0    -0.113145     0.538810    -0.043185    -0.150704     0.057516     0.046128     0.343291     0.039415    -0.118799     -0.155313      0.381745     -0.250619      0.343292     -0.315427     -0.122863      0.068318
6       0.560416            6.0    0.0    -0.204690     0.181405     0.543654     0.340886    -0.275855    -0.037939    -0.050138    -0.239225    -0.052624     -0.239889      0.117819      0.052465     -0.373745     -0.149760      0.156353     -0.179371
7      -0.403050            7.0    1.0    -0.178138    -0.281203    -0.081624     0.090432     0.090038    -0.427198    -0.084569    -0.062534     0.569291     -0.134243      0.239196     -0.085040      0.016309     -0.078131      0.113432      0.097394
8       1.202728            8.0    0.0     0.071775    -0.180170     0.087681    -0.318030    -0.142572     0.139888    -0.008269     0.168043     0.011826     -0.299417     -0.171258      0.052936     -0.101520     -0.211515     -0.154248      0.049600
9      -0.081895           10.0    1.0    -0.353030     0.077459    -0.044642     0.225100     0.078206     0.115056    -0.117477    -0.203697    -0.136310      0.074003     -0.313551      0.184199      0.171788     -0.074015      0.060184      0.428194
10     -0.884784           12.0    0.0    -0.183930     0.011794     0.095495     0.182962    -0.045277     0.198398     0.415487     0.507330     0.169621     -0.066478     -0.165655     -0.000376      0.133879      0.459423      0.324964     -0.064214
11      0.881572           13.0    1.0    -0.195712     0.218775    -0.177670    -0.200639    -0.208203    -0.025052     0.042678    -0.401426     0.275074      0.075878     -0.359991     -0.039838      0.072103      0.257290     -0.342703     -0.426637
12      1.523883           14.0    0.0     0.128607     0.480509    -0.385878     0.091855     0.056152    -0.134789    -0.352402     0.208674    -0.017009      0.200666      0.185478      0.041582     -0.337446      0.178371      0.190868     -0.087371
13     -1.045361           15.0    1.0     0.166597    -0.089110    -0.109782     0.104984     0.528854     0.529754    -0.056245    -0.326489     0.153271     -0.298661      0.157056     -0.061705     -0.097035      0.178674     -0.027044      0.043495
14     -0.242472           16.0    0.0    -0.085249     0.037130     0.142847    -0.251928     0.195658     0.027961    -0.248846    -0.007671     0.135104      0.343121     -0.248098     -0.064966      0.228748     -0.321116      0.422975      0.018823
15     -0.563628           17.0    1.0    -0.190203    -0.053749    -0.160313     0.149640    -0.063512    -0.206393    -0.264280     0.238996    -0.146314     -0.244733      0.020880      0.278250      0.181423      0.106724     -0.400457      0.237057
16     -1.205939           18.0    1.0    -0.083474    -0.194554     0.005645    -0.045870     0.003321     0.321345    -0.048387     0.106808    -0.108053      0.278396      0.292693      0.555157      0.063186     -0.166453     -0.074729     -0.392409
17      0.078683           19.0    0.0     0.138741    -0.283597     0.057301    -0.004913    -0.023166    -0.249826    -0.017610    -0.051725    -0.066780      0.012460      0.282140     -0.096769      0.381560      0.099963      0.068412     -0.286344
18      1.042150            9.0    1.0     0.283151    -0.208560    -0.415019     0.392379    -0.470813     0.187894     0.039962    -0.102994    -0.140439      0.044455     -0.102141     -0.281541      0.093164     -0.231794      0.139206     -0.001186
19      1.363305           11.0    0.0    -0.266310    -0.254019    -0.153286    -0.318855     0.105382    -0.209260     0.224933    -0.217558    -0.561887      0.017975      0.050319     -0.100827     -0.266410      0.227304      0.219550      0.048843

'''

Undertsanding ColumnTransformer :
ColumnTransformer applies its transformers in parallel.
When using a ColumnTransformer, if you pass the same column to multiple transformers,
that column will appear multiple times in the output, once for each transformation applied to it.
 from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'numeric_feature': [1, 2, 3],
    'categorical_feature': ['A', 'B', 'A']
})
print(data)
'''
   numeric_feature categorical_feature
0                1                   A
1                2                   B
2                3                   A
'''
ct = ColumnTransformer(
transformers = [
('num_identity','passthrough',['numeric_feature']),
#passing numeric_feature again
('num',StandardScaler(),['numeric_feature']),
('cat',OneHotEncoder(),['categorical_feature'])] )
transformedData = ct.fit_transform(data)
df_transformed = pd.DataFrame(
transformedData,columns = ['original_numeric','scaled_numeric','catA','catB'])
print(df_transformed)
'''
   original_numeric  scaled_numeric  catA  catB
0               1.0       -1.224745   1.0   0.0
1               2.0        0.000000   0.0   1.0
2               3.0        1.224745   1.0   0.0
'''

method 3 :
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.decomposition import IncrementalPCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from scipy.sparse import hstack, csr_matrix
import scipy.sparse

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'num_col1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],  # Numeric column to be standardized and reduced
    'lookupTable': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],    # Lookup table (should not be standardized)
    'cat_col': ['R', 'A', 'S', 'R', 'S'],  # Categorical column
    'text_col': ['R world', 'S fun', 'Data science', 'Text data', 'Preprocessing text']  # Text column
})
def selectNumCols(df1):
    aa = df1.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).columns.difference(['lookupTable'])
    return aa 

num_cols = selectNumCols(df)

n_components = min(2,len(num_cols))

if len(num_cols) > 1 :
    num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler',StandardScaler()),
    ('IPCA',IncrementalPCA(n_components = min(2,len(num_cols))))
        
    ])
else:
    num_pipeline = Pipeline([('scaler',StandardScaler())])  

# Define the column transformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', num_pipeline, num_cols),  # Apply the num_pipeline to numeric columns
        ('cat', OneHotEncoder(), ['cat_col']),   # Apply OneHotEncoder to the categorical column
        ('text', TfidfVectorizer(), 'text_col'),  # Apply TfidfVectorizer to the text column
        ('lookup', 'passthrough', ['lookupTable'])  # Pass through the lookup table column
    ]
    #sparse_threshold=0.3  # Keep sparse matrices when the data is more than 30% sparse
)

X = preprocessor.fit_transform(df)

num_cols = [f'num_ipca{i}' for i in range(n_components)] if len(num_cols) > 1 else list(num_cols)

oneHotColNames = preprocessor.named_transformers_['cat'].get_feature_names_out()
print(oneHotColNames)

tfidColNames = preprocessor.named_transformers_['text'].get_feature_names_out()
print(tfidColNames)

cols =  ['lookupTable'] + num_cols + list(oneHotColNames) + list(tfidColNames) 
print(cols)
X_df = pd.DataFrame(X,columns = cols)
print(X_df.to_string())
'''
   lookupTable  num_col1  cat_col_A  cat_col_R  cat_col_S  data       fun  preprocessing   science  text  world
0    -1.414214       0.0        1.0        0.0   0.000000   0.0  0.000000       0.000000  0.000000   1.0    1.0
1    -0.707107       1.0        0.0        0.0   0.000000   1.0  0.000000       0.000000  0.000000   0.0    2.0
2     0.000000       0.0        0.0        1.0   0.627914   0.0  0.000000       0.778283  0.000000   0.0    3.0
3     0.707107       0.0        1.0        0.0   0.707107   0.0  0.000000       0.000000  0.707107   0.0    4.0
4     1.414214       0.0        0.0        1.0   0.000000   0.0  0.778283       0.000000  0.627914   0.0    5.0

'''

method 5 :
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.decomposition import IncrementalPCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from scipy.sparse import hstack, csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from Only_Testing1.test1 import aa

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'num_col1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],  # Numeric column to be standardized and reduced
    'lookupTable': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],    # Lookup table (should not be standardized)
    'cat_col': ['R', 'A', 'S', 'R', 'S'],  # Categorical column
    'text_col': ['R world', 'S fun', 'Data science', 'Text data', 'Preprocessing text']  # Text column
})
# Custom function to select numeric columns except 'lookupTable'
def select_numeric_columns(X):
    return X.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).columns.difference(['lookupTable'])

# Determine the number of numeric columns after excluding 'lookupTable'
numeric_columns = select_numeric_columns(df)
n_numeric_features = len(numeric_columns)

# Set n_components to the minimum of 2 or the number of numeric features
n_components = min(2, n_numeric_features)

# Conditionally include IncrementalPCA in the pipeline
if n_numeric_features > 1:
    num_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('scaler', StandardScaler()),  # Standardize numeric data
        ('ipca', IncrementalPCA(n_components=n_components))   # Apply IncrementalPCA to reduce to n_components
    ])
else:
    num_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('scaler', StandardScaler())  # Standardize numeric data only (no PCA)
    ])

# Define the column transformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', num_pipeline, numeric_columns),  # Apply the num_pipeline to numeric columns
        ('cat', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=True), ['cat_col']),   # Apply OneHotEncoder to the categorical column
        ('text', TfidfVectorizer(), 'text_col'),  # Apply TfidfVectorizer to the text column
        ('lookup', 'passthrough', ['lookupTable'])  # Pass through the lookup table column
    ],
    sparse_threshold=0.3  # Keep sparse matrices when the data is more than 30% sparse
)

# Apply transformations
X = preprocessor.fit_transform(df)

# Convert dense matrix to sparse if it's not already sparse
if not isinstance(X, csr_matrix):
    X = csr_matrix(X)


# Automatically generate column names from transformers
num_cols = [f'num_ipca_{i+1}' for i in range(n_components)] if n_numeric_features > 1 else list(numeric_columns)
onehot_col_names = preprocessor.named_transformers_['cat'].get_feature_names_out(['cat_col'])
tfidf_feature_names = preprocessor.named_transformers_['text'].get_feature_names_out()

# Combine all the column names
cols = num_cols + list(onehot_col_names) + list(tfidf_feature_names) + ['lookupTable']

# Convert the resulting sparse matrix to a sparse DataFrame
X_df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(X, columns=cols)

print(X_df.to_string())
'''
   num_col1  cat_col_A  cat_col_R  cat_col_S      data  fun  preprocessing   science      text  world  lookupTable
0 -1.414214          0        1.0          0         0    0              0         0         0    1.0          1.0
1 -0.707107        1.0          0          0         0  1.0              0         0         0      0          2.0
2         0          0          0        1.0  0.627914    0              0  0.778283         0      0          3.0
3  0.707107          0        1.0          0  0.707107    0              0         0  0.707107      0          4.0
4  1.414214          0          0        1.0         0    0       0.778283         0  0.627914      0          5.0

'''


I tried this solution but did not get the expected result.   So I tried again on a smaller data set.  On a data frame of 480 rows and 16 columns, transforming only 1 column (text column), I got a data frame of 480 rows and 496 columns. I expected to get a 480 x 16 column

Use method 2. It is much more efficient than the first one. I have used LabelEncoder and PCA.

In ColumnTransformer,  If I use the dtype column selector and use the 'column name' selector is there a chance that columns are processed twice? In other words does ColumnTransformer work in parallel or serially?   I ask this because I realize that one int64 column is actually a lookup table, so although I want to use StandardScalar on most int64 columns I don't want to transform the look up tables.

Always Parallel.ColumnTransformer applies its transformers in parallel. When using a ColumnTransformer, if you pass the same column to multiple transformers, that column will appear multiple times in the output, once for each transformation applied to it. Added a small example to understand.

In using method #2. If I use the label encoder only, and no pipeline it works. But if I add the pipeline,  I get an error from the line: X = preprocessor.fit_transform(df) : ValueError: n_components=1 must be strictly less than min(n_samples, n_features)=1 with svd_solver='arpack'.  I believe the error is actually from the PCA statement.  However, I get the error no matter what my n_componants value is.  I have tried 0 to 16, and 480.?

Please try method 3(more efficient) and let me know.I have used IncrementalPCA with minimum clause. @Tavi. If it works then Good , but if Not,then I will use csr_matrix version for sparse datasets.

In your example there seem to be three types of fields:

string: use TfidfVectorizer
numeric: leave as it is
boolean: use LabelEncoder

So I'll use an example with just three fields, one of each kind
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

data = {
    'Numeric_col': [10, 20, 30],
    'Boolean_col': [True, False, True],
    'String_col': ['hello world', 'machine learning is fun', 'hello machine']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Boolean_col'] = df['Boolean_col'].astype(int)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['String_col'])

tfidf_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_matrix.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())

result_df = pd.concat([df[['Numeric_col', 'Boolean_col']], tfidf_df], axis=1)


Output
Numeric_col  Boolean_col       fun     hello        is  learning   machine  \
0           10            1  0.000000  0.605349  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
1           20            0  0.528635  0.000000  0.528635  0.528635  0.402040   
2           30            1  0.000000  0.707107  0.000000  0.000000  0.707107   

      world  
0  0.795961  
1  0.000000  
2  0.000000  

One problem with this is that the string fields can lead to an explosion in dimensionality (because in simple language there will be one column for every word in your vocabulary).
So if you want to achieve a more compact representation, you can use word embeddings like Word2Vec or BERT to take the average embedding of each word in the column after tokenization. One caveat here is that these embedding models sometimes don't have embeddings for certain words, so you would need to use a placeholder embedding in place (for example a 0 vector).
This is an (untested) example involving a Word2Vec model:
Install gemsim if you don't have it with pip install gensim.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# Download a pretrained GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz model and put th path below. It's a 3gbish large model (so beware).
word2vec_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/path/to/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)

data = {
    'String_col': ['hello world', 'machine learning is fun', 'hello machine']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def average_word2vec(sentence, model):
    tokens = word_tokenize(sentence.lower())
    embeddings = [model[word] for word in tokens if word in model]
    if embeddings:
        return np.mean(embeddings, axis=0)
    else:
        # If no embeddings are found, we'lll use a zero vector
        return np.zeros(model.vector_size)

df['Embedding'] = df['String_col'].apply(lambda x: average_word2vec(x, word2vec_model))

print(df)


I tried and tried to use the word2vect model but was thwarted by its size.

Using the first way you gave, using a smaller data set (480 rows x 16 columns) only transforming 1 text column I ended with a 480 x 480 data frame; which was not what I expected.  I expected the 1 column of text to be replaced by the vector.
